# Shopify Webhook for Order fulfillment firing Callback URL multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, shopify

I have set the Callback URL in the Order fulfillment webhook.

Now I have put the following code in PHP app:

```
$webhookContent = "";
$webhook = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent. = fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);
```

Now when I generate any order and fulfillment it's then the `Webhook` for Order fulfillment firing Callback URL multiple times, so how to fire for single time?

Comment: I found this too, what I had to do was really dirty and evil - if your response takes too long, the webhook will class it as failed and then resend another call so what I had to do was return an ok response immediately and then on a separate thread do all my processing in the background

Comment: wow. amazing what people call dirty and evil these days. I cannot imagine what one could call clean and nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhook call is fired multiple times when it doesn't get a success response from the callback URL. You can just try exiting after performing the required functionality. That will be something like:-

```
$webhookContent = "";
$webhook = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent. = fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);
exit;
```

Comment: But I needs to do further action after data received in webhook

Comment: Means I needs to send details of $webhook  to API.

Comment: @Tushar yes you can perform all required function. But make sure that there is not any issue with code you implement. Or it is not taking too long. If the process is going to take time, you can save the webhook data at your end and then just exit. Later on you can use this saved data for api calls or as you want.

Comment: so while webhook is called, you can just save its data for later processing.